# clicky api connection using php curl failed

Tags: php, curl

I wants to create a url for connecting with "Clicky API" like "http://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4?site_id=32145&sitekey=94d117119dsfa&type=visitors" so for this I have developed a cUrl code as below,

```
$url = 'http://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4';
$info = array(
            'site_id'=>'32145',
        'sitekey'=>'94d117119dsfa',
        'type'=>'visitors'
    );
    $post_field_string = http_build_query($info, ',', '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  "));
    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($exec);
```

But will get output as "Resource id #2" and when will check in inspect window the response will be as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response status="fail">
<error><![CDATA[The 'type' parameter is required.
     This specifies what data type(s) you want returned
     from the API.]]></error>
</response>
```

So, can anyone one tell me where I missed the step. please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I made it for a freelance client a while ago. It calls you PHP Script via JS and puts into the graph "googleCharts"

Explanation:

$_POST will have all the data that is needed to form the URL, siteid and key are statically placed in php file for security and file_get_contents() gets the data from clicky

```
<?php
// show all errors comment it when in production
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

//Allow from any origin or you can set your domain name here
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$input = $_POST;
//The data you send will now be used
$input['site_id'] = "yoursiteid";
$input['sitekey'] = "yoursitekey";
unset($input['url']);
$output = http_build_query($input);
$url = $_POST['url']."?".$output;
$data = file_get_contents($url);

print_r($data);
?>
```

This is the main.html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<body>
    <div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    <button onclick="change('/auction-list/');">Change URL</button>
    <div id="map_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {
        packages: ["map", "line"]
    });
</script>
<script>

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(new_req);
    var url = "http://localhost/clicky.php";
    var item = "/business-development/"; 
    var frequency = "daily";
    var date = "last-30-days";
    var type = "pages";
    function change(myitem){
        item = myitem;
        new_req();
    }
    function new_req() {
        console.log(item);
        var fdata = {
            "url": "https://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4",
            "type": type,
            "date": date,
            "output": "json",
            "frequency": frequency,
            "item": item,
            "daily": "1"
        };
        ajax_request(url, fdata, format_chart_data);
        var gdata = {
            "url": "https://api.clicky.com/api/stats/4",
            "type": "regions",
            "date": date,
            "output": "json"
        };
        ajax_request(url, gdata, format_graph_data);
    }

    function ajax_request(url, data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            timeout: 40000,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: callback,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                response = "err--" + XMLHttpRequest.status + " -- " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function format_chart_data(result) {
        console.log(result);
        var graph_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        graph_data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        graph_data.addColumn('number', 'Visitors');
        graph_data.addColumn('number', 'Blank');
        var data = result[0].dates;
        var i = 0;
        var j = data.length;
        console.log(data.reverse());
        for (var i in data) {
            var date = data[i].date.split("-");
            var year = date[0];
            var month = date[1];
            var day = date[2];

            graph_data.addRow([(day + " / " + month + " / " + year), parseInt(data[i].items[0].value), 0]);
        }


        var chart1_options = {
            title: "Stats",
            vAxis: {
                title: "Listing",
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
        chart.draw(graph_data, chart1_options);


    }

    function format_graph_data(result) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        var map_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        map_data.addColumn('string', 'Regions');
        map_data.addColumn('string', 'Name [Percentage]');

        var drt = result[0].dates[0].date.split(",");
        var date_range = "From " + drt[0] + " To " + drt[1];
        console.log(date_range);
        var data = result[0].dates[0].items;
        for (var i in data) {
            map_data.addRow([data[i].title, data[i].title+" ["+data[i].value_percent+"%]"]);

        }
        var chart2_options = {
            showTip: true
        };
        var Map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
        Map.draw(map_data, chart2_options);

        setTimeout(function() {
            //  new_req("default");
        }, 40000);
    }
</script>
```